# Error occurred during initialization of VM while running jdevloper

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

When running java programs in javadeveloper IDE,

Error is coming Error occurred during initialization of VM

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file 
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_18\jre\lib\rt.jar Process exited with exit
>   code 1.

while the same path is there in my machine

SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_18\bin;

Running first time it is correct but when run again this problem is re occurs then again close and reopen the IDE it will work first run as fine but again same problem will come.

Please help .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like your JDeveloper is pointing to a JRE instead of a full blown JDK.
Try to reinstall JDeveloper pointing to the JDK instead.